# Major device number and its corresponding module name

Tags: rhel, kernel-modules, devices

If I know a device's major device number how do I know which kernel module this relates to?  In hpux I can use lsdev to see a list of major numbers and their associated modules names - is there an equivalent in RHEL 7.x ?

Answer (score 2):

```
cat /proc/devices
```

should do the trick

Comment: Please elaborate (and properly format) your answer.